# Java - Creating a JFrame using GridLayout with mouse-interactive JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

(Beginner)
Hi, sorry for the specific question, but I'm having errors constantly ambush me out of nowhere with a program that I would expect to be quite simple.

I was planning on creating a program that would allow the user to click on JPanels with in a GridLayout in order to change their colours. Imagine a poor man's pixel art program, like the old MS Paint.
The plan was to create a JFrame set to GridLayout, of an integer width and height, and fill the grids with JPanels with a 2d array and a for loop. I would then put a MouseListener into each individual JPanel to listen for a mouseClicked, which would change the background colour of the panel clicked.

```
package pixelpainter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class PixelPainter extends JPanel {
int width = 20;
int height = 20;
int pixSize = 10;
Color bGColor = Color.WHITE;
Dimension pixDim = new Dimension(pixSize,pixSize);
private JPanel panelClicked = null;
JFrame frame= new JFrame();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public PixelPainter()
{
    initGUI();
}

public void initGUI() {

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(height, width, 0, 0));
    frame.setSize((height * pixSize), (width * pixSize));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    int[][] pixGrid = new int [width][height];

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            JPanel pixel[][] = new JPanel[width][height];
            frame.add(pixel[row][col]);
            pixel[row][col].setBackground(bGColor);
            pixel[row][col].setPreferredSize(pixDim);
            pixel[row][col].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            pixel[row][col].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
            {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click)
                {
                    JPanel selectedPixel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(click.getPoint());
                    if (selectedPixel == null || selectedPixel == PixelPainter.this)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (selectedPixel != null)
                    {
                        selectedPixel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent press)
                {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
                public void run(){
                    new PixelPainter().setVisible(true);
                }
            });     
    }

}
```

Ideally I would be using the 2d array JFrame when filling in the colours, but apparently they must be final or effectively final.

Answer (score 2):

I rearranged your code to group like things together.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Pixel Art GUI]

I made the following changes to your code.

1. I had the main class implement Runnable.  Since the EventQueue invokeLater method expects a Runnable, you might as well make the main class a Runnable.
2. I moved the JPanel creation into the createPixels method.  Your methods should do one thing and do that one thing well.
3. The initGUI method now just creates the JFrame.
4. I moved the sizing integers into the new PixelPanel class.  The class that extends a JPanel has to provide a preferred size.  The JFrame pack method then creates a JFrame of the correct size.
5. In the paintComponent method of the PixelPanel class, all I do is paint.  You shouldn't do anything else but paint in the paintComponent method.
6. I made the pixels bigger, so I could left click and right click on a pixel easier.  The left click makes the pixel blue, and the right click erases the blue (makes the pixel white).
7. Because of the [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), I pulled the mouse adapter code into its own class.  Separating the concerns makes getting each part of the GUI working properly much easier.

And here's the code.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PixelPainter implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new PixelPainter());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        initGUI();
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Pixel Art");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createPixels());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPixels() {
        int width = 30;
        int height = 20;

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(height, width, 0, 0));

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++) {
                PixelPanel pixelPanel = new PixelPanel();
                pixelPanel.addMouseListener(new ColorListener(pixelPanel));
                panel.add(pixelPanel);
            }
        }

        return panel;
    }

    public class PixelPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8465814529701152253L;

        private static final int PIXEL_SIZE = 20;

        private Color backgroundColor;

        public PixelPanel() {
            this.backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PIXEL_SIZE, PIXEL_SIZE));
        }

        public Color getBackgroundColor() {
            return backgroundColor;
        }

        public void setBackgroundColor(Color backgroundColor) {
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(getBackgroundColor());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public class ColorListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private PixelPanel panel;

        public ColorListener(PixelPanel panel) {
            this.panel = panel;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                panel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                panel.repaint();
            } else if (event.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                panel.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                panel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating a new pixel Array inside the loop. The idea is to create the Array out side the loo and then create a new JPanel to add to the Array inside the loop.

Something like:

```
int[][] pixGrid = new int [width][height];
JPanel pixel[][] = new JPanel[width][height];
```

and

```
 //JPanel pixel[][] = new JPanel[width][height];
 pixel[row][col] = new JPanel();
```

Now inside the listener because you add the listener to every panel you can access the panel directly without worrying about the mouse point:

```
 //JPanel selectedPixel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(click.getPoint());
 JPanel selectedPixel = (JPanel)click.getSource();
```

In fact you can create a single MouseListener to add to each panel instead of creating a different listener for each panel because the above code is generic.